# Why FF Adblock blocks even my js code?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, adblock

In my project I have many javascript code. But I saw that adblock blocks even my code!!! 
On one page it blocks all javascript code!
Some friends told me that on their computers adblock blocks jQuery Validation Plugin (registration page of my site)...

How to prevent it? Thanks!

Comment: Disable the plugin or use a different browser? Adblock removes scripts based on name etc.

Comment: This might help clear up the confusion: http://adblockplus.org/en/getting_started#general